# Order the panels from right to left in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a data frame with 5 groups.
I want to facet my data by group using ggplot. I need the panels to be ordered from right to left, and not from left to right (the default).

```
df <- data.frame(group=letters[1:5],
       x=1:5,
       y=1:5)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point(size=3) + 
facet_wrap(~group)
```

By default the panels are ordered from left to right, so that group 'a' appears at the top-left of the graph. The panel at the bottom-right is empty (as there are only 5 groups). I want the panels to appear from right to left. That is, 'a' should appear at the top-right and the panel at the left-bottom should be empty. Any ideas?

Note: the question is not about the labels of the panels. It is also not about re-ordering the group with factor().
I looked at the facet_wrap() help, but the only options are the 'switch' and 'strip.position' arguments that deal with labels. The 'dir' argument allows vertical or horizontal position, which is not what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want an empty plot panel in the bottom left, or just white space?

Comment: I need a just a white space. Exactly as it appears now, but from right to left.

Comment: There are a few answers on SO with methods for this. For example, [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30372692/496488).

Comment: It seems that the proposed solution there, does not work with the new version of ggplot. As there is a 'dir' argument taking v or h value, tt should be a simple argument for right-left or left-right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that's somewhat hacky, because it requires manual positioning. We create a plotting function and then plot the first row of plots (rows 1 to 3 of `df` and the second row of plots (rows 4 and 5 of `df`) separately. We lay them out using `grid.arrange`, but we add a blank plot with just the y-axis at the left end of the second row to create the blank space.

The manual adjustment of the `widths` argument is necessary to get the blank plot to take up just the right amount of space so that the other two plots line up vertically with the plots above.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

pf = function(data, xrng=range(df$x), yrng=range(df$y)) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point(size=3) + 
    facet_wrap(~ factor(group, rev(group))) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=yrng) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=xrng)
}

grid.arrange(pf(df[1:3,]), 
             arrangeGrob(pf(data.frame(x=-10,y=-10, group="x")) + 
                           theme(panel.border=element_blank(),
                                 panel.background=element_blank(),
                                 strip.background=element_rect(colour=NA, fill=NA),
                                 strip.text=element_text(colour=NA),
                                 axis.text.x=element_text(colour=NA),
                                 axis.title.x=element_text(colour=NA),
                                 axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
                                 axis.title.y=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5),
                                 axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0),
                                 axis.ticks.y=element_line()), 
                         pf(df[4:5,]) + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                                              axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                                              axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) , 
                         widths=c(1.12,2)), 
             ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Add df$group = factor(df$group, levels=rev(df$group)), as suggested earlier (a deleted comment). So the group will appear in reverse. Also, is it possible to align the y axis of the two lines?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to take the y-axis ticks and labels from the bottom row of plots and move it to the left so that it is directly under the y-axis ticks and labels of the top row of plots?

Comment: exactly. That would answer my question perfectly